# Mechanizer in python - selecting form field with no name

Tags: python, forms, mechanize-python

I have a problem similar to [Selecting an unnamed text field in a mechanize form (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787907/selecting-an-unnamed-text-field-in-a-mechanize-form-python) and [Use mechanize to submit form without control name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965285/use-mechanize-to-submit-form-without-control-name/14009072#14009072) .

I want to scrape the data of a website behind a login screen. However, I don't know how to select a form field that does not have a name. The controls look like this:

```
<TextControl(<None>=)>
<PasswordControl(<None>=)>
<CheckboxControl(<None>=[on])>
<SubmitButtonControl(<None>=) (readonly)>>
```

Usually it says `<TextControl(login=)>`, so I can use `br.form['login'] = 'mylogin'` But this time I can't, since I don't know the name of the login field.

I'm able to access the form, but cannot fill out the TextControl or PasswordControl due to the  value I guess. My basic code looks like this:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 
import cookielib

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

url = "www.example.com"
request = urllib2.Request(url, None, hdr)
response = br.open(request)
forms =  [form for form in br.forms()][0]
br.select_form(nr=0)
```

I tried stuff like this:

```
br.form.find_control(id="id").value = "loginname"
```

and this:

```
forms[0].set_value("new value", nr=0)
```

This throws errors such as `mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` or `TypeError: control name must be string-like`. I don't know what else to try. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code:

```
url = "www.example.com"
request = urllib2.Request(url, None, hdr)
response = br.open(request)
forms =  [form for form in br.forms()][0]
br.select_form(nr=0)
```

Following this:

```
aux = 0
for f in br.form.controls:
    print f,
    print '   ---> Number: ',
    print aux
    aux = aux + 1
```

The results is:

```
<TextControl(<None>=)>   ---> Number:  0 
<PasswordControl(<None>=)>   ---> Number:  1
<CheckboxControl(<None>=[on])>   ---> Number:  2
<SubmitButtonControl(<None>=) (readonly)>   ---> Number:  3
```

Now, you can try this:

```
br.form.controls[0]._value = "loginname"
br.form.controls[1]._value = "password"
```

So:

```
for f in br.form.controls:
    print f
```

The results will be:

```
<TextControl(<None>=loginname)>
<PasswordControl(<None>=password)>
<CheckboxControl(<None>=[on])>
<SubmitButtonControl(<None>=) (readonly)>
```