# Using mechanize to run search form with no name for the input field

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I have a list of tennis players stored in a database. I want to use mechanize to scrape the atpworldtour.com site for information on those players. The search form is located on the home page and I can access it pretty easily with:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
url = "http://www.atpworldtour.com"
page = agent.get(url)
form = page.form()
```

However the input field has no name.Here's the markup for the search form:

```
<form id="siteSearch" class="site-search">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search Players and Tournaments" class="search">
  <button id="closeSearch" type="button" class="close-search"></button>
  <div class="search-partner"><span> </span><img alt="" src=""></div>
</form>
```

I've tried to search ways to access a field with no name and came across [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27486361/mechanizer-in-python-selecting-form-field-with-no-name) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787907/selecting-an-unnamed-text-field-in-a-mechanize-form-python) questions but they both use the `find_control` method and I think that's python specific? It gives me an `undefined method 'find_control'` error at any rate.

I also had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955267/using-ruby-and-mechanize-to-fill-in-a-remote-login-form-mystery) and also took a look at the [mechanize documentation](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Form.html) for `field_with` and came up with:

```
pp form.field_with(:class => "search").value
```

to try and print out the current value of the search field to see if that works but `form.field_with(:class => "search")` returns `nil`.

Am I going about this the wrong way? If anyone can point me towards the right path for at least getting the search submitted I'd much appreciate it.

Comment: That input doesn't have a name so it doesn't do anything in the form sense. I see that it's firing off ajax requests to http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/-/ajax/PredictiveContentSearch/GetPlayerResults/foo and http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/-/ajax/PredictiveContentSearch/GetTournamentResults/foo

Comment: Yeah I feel silly for not realising this sooner. Got a whole different problem on my hands now. Thanks for the feedback :)